# Unity3D EditorScript AddComponentMenu item is not displayed in Component Menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use an EditorScript I found [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14567/editing-mesh-vertices-in-unity.html) within Unity Editor.
I would expect it to appear as a menu item in the Component/Mesh menu but I can't get it to display. It just won't appear.
I also tried with this very basic script:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[AddComponentMenu("Mesh/Test Editor Script")]
public class TestEditorScript : MonoBehaviour {
  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {
  }
}
```

I also tried restarting Unity and using a completely new Unity project.

However, the script seems to be compiled, because, when I add errors to the code I get error messages in the console.

I put the script in the Assets/Editor folder and named it TestEditorScript.cs.

What am I doing wrong or how can I debug the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put such a script in a folder named "Editor". This is a [special name for folders in a Unity Project](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html):

> All scripts that are placed in a folder called Editor (or a sub-folder within it) will be treated as editor scripts rather than runtime scripts. Such scripts are designed to add functionality to Unity itself during development and are not available to the finished game at runtime. More than one Editor folder can be used in the project at once but note that the exact location of a given Editor folder affects the time at which its scripts will be compiled relative to other scripts. See the page on Special Folders and Script Compilation Order for a full description of this. Note: **Unity will not allow components derived from MonoBehaviour to be assigned to GameObjects if the scripts are in the Editor folder**.

So if you put a Monobehaviour in there, you won't be able to assign it to a GameObject and it won't appear in a menu to do so as a result.

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear in my question: Using the Script within Unity Editor and not in game is exactly what I want.

Comment: Then it can't be a Monobehaviour. What are you trying to achieve really?

Comment: Well, I just wanted to use the Vertex Handler Script from [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14567/editing-mesh-vertices-in-unity.html) (scroll down to Luke Kelletts answer). Unity documentation also seems to state that Component menu entries have to be MonoBehaviours ([link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AddComponentMenu.html)).

Comment: Sure, that could work, but then don't put it in a folder named "Editor". And include the [ExecuteInEditMode] attribute if you want it to run even when you don't press play. But if what you really want to do is extend the editor, have a look at http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExtendingTheEditor.html